# Minecraft not showing the port when opening the server to LAN - now what?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My kids have two Ubuntu machines running Minecraft Java Edition. Everything used to work fine with them playing together, but since they've downloaded the latest version opening the game to LAN no longer shows the message saying "server opened on [port]".

They are also unable to find each other normally in the "looking for games" multiplayer-menu.

Oddly enough, if my wife runs Minecraft on her Windows machine, it all works fine; she gets the message and my kids can join her session.

What might be going on here? There's been no changes to the OS itself, so I feel like this is something that's changed on the Minecraft end, but I have no idea where to look for the problem without any feedback. It just seems to open to LAN on the Ubuntu machines and not show the message and they can both connect to the Windows machine fine; they just can't see each other or list the port.

Comment: Can you post an image of the message on the Windows Machine that you are expecting to see on the Ubuntu machines?

Comment: The chat is probably hidden. Change Options... -> Chat Settings... -> Chat: Hidden.